# How to match predicted class and prabablity with actual labels

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, predict, one-hot-encoding

I have trained a deep learning model based on Bidirectional LSTM and dense layer output. It is quite confusing that which output probability acquired using `model.predict(x)` matches with my actual label (one hot encoded labels). Moreover, the `model.predict_classes(x)` outputs (0,1,2) are also confusing. How can i relate these outputs with my original labels. Below is my code snippet for reference:

```
model = Sequential()

model.add(Embedding(MAX_NB_WORDS, EMBEDDING_DIM, input_length=X.shape[1]))
model.add(SpatialDropout1D(0.5))


model.add(Bidirectional(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(250, return_sequences=True,activation='tanh')))
model.add(Bidirectional(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(250)))

model.add(Dropout(0.5))



model.add(Dense(3, activation='softmax'))
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
#model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=Adam(), metrics=['accuracy'])
print(model.summary())

history = model.fit(X_train, Y_train, validation_data=(X_test, Y_test), batch_size=32, epochs=10)

model.predict_classes(test_doc)
model.predict(test_doc)
```

If someone please help to identify the outputs with actual labels in this sequential model.

Comment: Hard to tell without seeing any processing you've done for your labels

Comment: @NicolasGervais i have converted my labels i.e. 0,1,2 in one-hot-encoding using `Y = pd.get_dummies(df['Sentiment']).values`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have made a one hot encoding for your labels (0, 1, 2), you will have vectors as output of your model.

So, for example, if you have an instance with class 0, you'll target vector will be:

```
[1, 0, 0]
```

if you have an instance with class 1, your target vector will be:

```
[0, 1, 0]
```

if you have an instance with class 2, your target vector will be:

```
[0, 0, 1]
```

The method `.predict`, will give you a probability for every class in your target. So because you have 3 classes (0, 1, 2), you'll get a vector of size three with three probabilities

```
model.predict(x) # vector of size 3 with 3 probabilities
```

Something like this:

```
#class0, class1, class2
[0.31,   0.4,    0.29]
```

And these probabilities will sum to 1 because you have used the softmax activation function.

The method `.predict_classes`, will select for you the class with the highest probability from the vector and will make the decode

So if you have a probabilities vector of:

```
#class0, class1, class2
[0.31,   0.4,    0.29]
```

you'll get 1, because the max value in the vector is the one with index 1 in the target vector, the which represent the class 1

PS. You can make the model do the one hot encoding, changing the loss as "sparse_categorical_crossentropy":

```
model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Without using `pd.get_dummies(df['Sentiment']).value`

Comment: Thanks for the kind answer. The problem is still unclear that in which order shall we consider the probabilities. Because it may happen that the doc having label 1 may appear first and 0 and 2 may appear later.

Comment: @BilalChandio try to make the encoding with 'sparse_categorical_crossentropy'. Without using pd.get_dummies(df['Sentiment']).value

Comment: `sparse_categorical_crossentropy` is suitable when the number of classes is more. However, I tried this too but my network requires the labels to be one-hot-encoded.

Comment: sparse categorical crossentropy transform your labels under the hood as one hot encoder vectors

Comment: The question is still unanswered that which probablity among these `array([[0.31454232, 0.181991  , 0.50346667]], dtype=float32)` represent which class either 0,1, or 2

Comment: it depends on the encoding obtained from get_dummies. I suppose it could be something like this:

[1, 0, 0] -> 0
[0, 1, 0] -> 1
[0, 0, 1] -> 2

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html